# task.getResult().getDownloadUrl() method not working

Tags: android

```
private void storeFirestore(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task, String user_name) 
{

    Uri download_uri;

    if(task != null) {

        download_uri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl();

    } else {

        download_uri = mainImageURI;

    }

    Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    userMap.put("name", user_name);
    userMap.put("image", download_uri.toString());

    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "The user Settings are updated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();

            } else {

                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "(FIRESTORE Error) : " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });


}
```

getDownloadUrl not working up with red line under it , or is the downloadUrl need to add in a method for it.

Answer (score 4):

In Firebase Storage API version 16.0.1. The getDownloadUrl() method does not works if used as follows
`download_uri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl();`

Therefore we need to use Storage reference in order to use getDownloadUrl() method as follows:

```
final UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(resultUri);

uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String download_url = uri.toString();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
task.getResult().getDownloadUrl()
```

by

```
task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/firebase/codelab-friendlychat-android/issues/51#issuecomment-396117111)